# how can I append a multi-line variable to an array

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting

I have a multi-line variable in a bash script (contains output from a command that is executed automatically via SSH). How can I append this variable to an array so that each line in the variable is put into a new row/member of the array?

```
something="first row
           second row
           third row"

echo "${something_array[0]}" - first row
echo "${something_array[1]}" - second row
echo "${something_array[2]}" - third row
```

There "could" already be data inside the array, therefore I am try to append the lines to the array. I have already tried

```
IFS='\n' something_array=($(echo -e "$something"))
```

although I ran into some issues, plus it does not append the data either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted to use [`ANSI-C Quoting`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) for defining `IFS`.  Say:

```
IFS=$'\n' something_array=($(echo -e "$something"))
```

instead.

In order to append to the array, say:

```
IFS=$'\n' something_array+=($(echo -e "$something"))
```

Comment: Thanks! would you know how to append data with that by any chance? I tried += after the variable but it resulted in all data being placed in the first row of the array [0]

Comment: @lacrosse1991 No, saying `IFS=$'\n' something_array+=($(echo -e "$something"))` should append.